# Full screen background image is being cropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following JavaScript companied with basic CSS to create a parallax background image, live preview of what I already have in a demonstration here: http://loai.directory

Here is the Javascript:

```
//Parallax background image
var velocity = 0.5;

function update() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        return;
    }
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.parallax').each(function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        var height = $element.height();
        $(this).css('background-position', '50%' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) + 'px');
    });
};
$(window).on('scroll', update);
update();
```

CSS:

```
/*Backgruond Parallax*/
 .parallax {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

     #gallery .parallax {
        background-image: url('../images/image.jpg');
        padding: 100px 0;
    }

    #gallery .parallax.A {
        background-image: url('../images/backgruond.jpg');
        padding: 100px 0;
    }
```

And finally the HTML:

```
<div class="topSection parallax">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

---

The problem I am having is with the background images being cropped from the bottom, and the far you scroll down, the worse they get! I believe this is because the parallax function move the background image position to the top as you scroll... but how can I fix this? Please help.

[image]

The blue sections suppose to be filled with the background image.

Comment: You know you can stretch/resize background images using just CSS without JS?

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried setting the size of your background image in your css?

Comment: Yes, indeed! I tried background-size: 100%; and cover but same problem

Comment: I have also tried and change var $element = $(this); to var $element = $("html"); this improved things slightly but didn't really fix it completely

Comment: how about `background-size:contain;`?

Comment: Have you tried  `background-size: 100% 100%;`? It should completely cover the content area with this